# Swift: difference in () vs. () -> Void in animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to animate an image but the following:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [ .curveEaseIn], animations: self.space1ImageView.center.x += 1, completion: nil)
```

return the error:

```
'+= produces '()', not the expected contextual result type '() -> Void
```

This is all being done within an IBAction Button press

Comment: animations param is a closure

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [ .curveEaseIn], animations: {
  self.space1ImageView.center.x += 1
}, completion: nil)
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [ .curveEaseIn],animations: { 
     self.space1ImageView.center.x += 1
}, completion: nil)
```